# Cannot print on another paper tray via IPP

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing

I'm trying to print a document on the second paper tray with IPP (Internet Printing Protocol). I'm using this [npm IPP-Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipp).

But at any time i try to print a document my printer shows a message that i need to add paper to the first paper tray and the console output of says `Printed: successful-ok`.

```
var ipp = require("ipp");
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
var concat = require("concat-stream");

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.text("Hello World");

doc.pipe(concat(function (data) {
    var printer = ipp.Printer("MY_URL");

    var file = {
        "operation-attributes-tag": {
            "requesting-user-name": "admin",
            'attributes-charset': 'utf-8',
            'attributes-natural-language': 'de'
        },
        "printer-attributes": {
            "media-col": {
                "media-source": "tray-2"
            },
        },
        data: data
    };
    printer.execute("Print-Job", file, function (err, res) {
        console.log("Printed: " + res.statusCode);
    });
}));

doc.end();
```

The other variant i tried is following (from [here](https://github.com/williamkapke/ipp/issues/43)):

```
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
let fs = require('fs')
var ipp = require('ipp');
var uri = "http://10.1.205.71";


var msg = new Buffer(
  '0200'+ //Version
  '000201e6d5f2'+
  '01'+ //Operation attributes tag (your information in the Operation attributes might be different)
    '47'+ //charset tag
    '0012'+ //length
    '617474726962757465732d63686172736574'+ //attributes-charset
    '0005'+ //length
    '7574662d38'+ //utf-8
    '48'+ //natural language tag
    '001b'+ //length
    '617474726962757465732d6e61747572616c2d6c616e6775616765'+//attributes-natural-language
    '0002'+//length
    '656e'+ //en
    '45'+ // URI tag
    '000b'+ //length
    '7072696e7465722d757269'+ //printer-uri
    '0012'+//length
    '687474703a2f2f31302e312e3230352e3731'+//http://10.1.205.71
    '49'+ //mimeMediaType tag
    '000f'+ //length
    '646f63756d656e742d666f726d6174'+ //document format
    '000f'+ //length
    '6170706c69636174696f6e2f706466'+ //application/pdf
  '02'+ //job attributes tag
    '34'+ //begin collection
      '0009'+ //length
      '6d656469612d636f6c'+ //media-col
      '0000'+ //value length
      '4a'+ //collection entry
      '0000'+ //name length
      '000c'+ //value length
      '6d656469612d736f75726365'+ //media-source
      '44'+ // collection entry
      '0000'+ //name length
      '0006'+ //value length
      '747261792d32'+ //tray-2
    '37'+ //end of collection
    '00000000'+ //name length and value length
  '03', 'hex');

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.text("Hello World");

var buffers = [];
doc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
doc.on('end', function(){
  var buf = Buffer.concat(buffers);
  var catBuf = Buffer.concat([msg, buf]);
  ipp.request(uri, catBuf, function(err, res){
    if(err){
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res,null,2));
  });
});
doc.end();
```

But then i got this error message:

```
{ 
Error
    at new IppResponseError (/Users/alex/dev/print/printing/node_modules/ipp/lib/request.js:72:17)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/alex/dev/print/printing/node_modules/ipp/lib/request.js:40:8)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:522:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:411:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
  name: 'IppResponseError',
  statusCode: 400,
  message: 'Received unexpected response status 400 from the printer',
  stack: 'Error\n    at new IppResponseError (/Users/alex/dev/print/printing/node_modules/ipp/lib/request.js:72:17)\n    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/alex/dev/print/printing/node_modules/ipp/lib/request.js:40:8)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:191:7)\n    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:522:21)\n    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)\n    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:411:20)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)' }
400 'response'
```

My printer does not support IPP, but i shared it on my Macbook, which provides an IPP service for all shared printers.
If i'm using the first paper tray and have paper in there everything is fine, but for my project it is necessary to print on other trays, too.

The attributes' list returned from `Get-Printer-Attributes` lists among other trays the second paper as supported `media-source`, but ***only*** the first paper tray works.

Does anyone have an idea how to print successfully on another paper tray?

**Update:** I also tried another printer, but i got the same error.

**Update 22.06.17:** It's still confused and don't have any clue how to fix this.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/williamkapke/ipp/issues/43

Comment: Thanks for referencing the issue my code based on =) I totally forgot to add the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since i asked for help. Thanks to all for their contribution =)

I tried all suggested solutions from here and Github, but none of them worked, but I found a solution to solve my issue.

```
var ipp = require("ipp");
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
var concat = require("concat-stream");

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.text("Hello World");

doc.pipe(concat(function (data) {
    var printer = ipp.Printer("MY_URL");

    var file = {
        "operation-attributes-tag": {
            "requesting-user-name": "admin",
            'attributes-charset': 'utf-8',
            'attributes-natural-language': 'de'
        },
        "printer-attributes": {
            // OLD WAY WHICH DOES NOT WORK
            //"media-col": {
            //    "media-source": "tray-2"
            //},
        },
        // SOLUTION 
        "job-attributes-tag":{
            "media":  ["tray-2"]
        },
        data: data
    };

    printer.execute("Print-Job", file, function (err, res) {
        console.log("Printed: " + res.statusCode);
    });

}));

doc.end();
```

I tried this, because [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2566) (4.2.11) is `media` described with:

> The values for "media" include medium-names, medium-sizes, input-
> trays and electronic forms so that one attribute specifies the media.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that [this pull request](https://github.com/williamkapke/ipp/pull/40) might be able to solve the issue you're having. Until the author of `ipp` merges the pull request, you can update your npm package to point to that patch by running the following in your project directory:

```
npm i --save ipp@github:jaymcaliley/ipp
```

Answer (score 0):

The response to the request that you are sending is with the status code of 400 to the request that was issued to the printer.

This can be seen here [on line 30](https://github.com/williamkapke/ipp/blob/master/lib/request.js).

This can be caused by a firewall configuration or wrong network setting.

You need to specify correctly the URL for the printer like in this example and to check if this URL is valid and the printer responds to it:

```
  var printer = ipp.Printer("http://NPI977E4E.local.:631/ipp/printer");
```